# WinAPI Linking c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Win7 64bit
Qt5.4.1 -> MinGW 4.9.1 32bit

Below is a simple Qt app that generates unique GUID:

guid.pro

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = qt-msync
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Include"
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/Rpcrt4.lib"

TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <Rpc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    GUID myGuid;
    CoCreateGuid(&myGuid);

    return a.exec();
}
```

If the qmake contains
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Include"
I am struck with 72 errors all of which look like errors related to double underscore macros.

As it stands 
\main.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `_imp__CoCreateGuid@4'
Obviously a linker error but library file is present
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/Rpcrt4.lib"

Anyone else managed to get Rpc.h to cooperate compiling a 32 target on 64 Machine ?

I have also tried simpler CMake C++ only code compiling with MSVC (the one included in the Windows SDK) and it throws the same error.

Comment: That's COM, so you need some com lib(s). MSDN shows it as Objbase.h / Ole32.lib, since you're getting to linking, you must just need the Ole32.lib. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The documented header is `<objbase.h>`, but curiously `<rpc.h>` (as you're using) works with both g++ and MSVC. Re the linking error, just link with the documented library. In short, **read the documentation**.

Comment: Couldn't see the trees through the forest I removed <objbase.h> during debugging . Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Include"
#LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/Rpcrt4.lib"

win32
{
    LIBS += -lole32
}
```

I was able to build exactly your code using only ole32.lib.

Comment: ole32 has #include <rpc.h> interesting

Comment: MSDN thinks you need to include Objbase.h https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms688568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx